# Reactjs add onClick attribute on a dynamic element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to create a table dynamically from the data received from an ajax response in a react app. The loop is created from the response of an ajax request inside the `useEffect` hook. The problem is that I can't make work the onClick attribute in an anchor tag in a table cell. Below is the code.

```
res.data.users.forEach(function (user) {
          let row = table.insertRow(rowcnt);
          let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          cell1.innerHTML = user.u_id;
          cell2.innerHTML = user.username;
          cell3.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-feather="edit"></span></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={(e) => deleteUser(e, ' + user.id + ')}><span data-feather="trash"></span></a>';
          rowcnt++;
        });
```

But in the frontend it is showing

[image]

Please help.

Comment: You should use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) instead of `innerHTML = "element string"` for much more readable code. Your onClick is also confusing, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I think you don't use react at it should be, maybe it will be better to set the given data inside a state, and construct your table depending on it... no ?

Comment: @Jesper        Call axios.delete to delete the user.

Comment: @BENARDPatrick Yes, I am newbie in react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "React way" is to use:

1. [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to maintain the data.
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the user data held in state and produce array of HTML for each user. Add an id to each `tr` element.
3. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in `deleteUser` function to filter out the row data where the `u_ids` don't match the id of the deleted row, and use that array to update the state at which point the component will be re-rendered with the updated state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const [ users, setUsers ] = useState(data.users);

  function deleteUser(id) {
    // Call Axios with the id to delete that item
    const filtered = users.filter(user => user.u_id !== id);
    setUsers(filtered);
  }

  function getRows(users) {
    return users.map(user  => {
      const { u_id, username } = user;
      return (
        <tr key={u_id} id={u_id}>
          <td>{u_id}</td>
          <td>{username}</td>
          <td class="delete">
            <a onClick={() => deleteUser(u_id)}>Delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
  }

  return (
    <table>
     {getRows(users)}
    </table>
  );
};

const data = {
  users: [
    {u_id: 1, username: 'Steve'},
    {u_id: 2, username: 'Polly'},
    {u_id: 3, username: 'Brian'},
    {u_id: 4, username: 'Billy Joel'}
  ]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.delete { background-color: red; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: In delete function I need to call axios and delete data from database, then refresh the table.

Comment: I can only provide a small example of how you should approach the problem. There was no mention of Axios in your question, but just calling Axios within that function with the row id should be very simple.

Comment: But the users data is also getting from the axios call. So what is the use of `useState`?

Comment: Because that's how React deals with data. State updates, then the component updates.

Comment: But I cannot use `useState` inside axios. I am getting error `React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: Now I have another problem. It is causing loop of ajax requests. I have posted it as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172124/reactjs-using-usestate-causing-loop-of-axios-requests

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `jsx` to instead of `innerHTML`, like this:

```
return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>u_id</th>
        <th>usename</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {res.data.users.map(user => (
        <tr>
          <td>{user.u_id}</td>
          <td>{user.username}</td>
          <td>
            <a onClick={(e) => deleteUser(e, ' + user.id + ')}>delete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)
```

Comment: The loop is created from the response of an ajax request inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: The table is already there. I am just creating the rows.