# Reactjs using useState causing loop of axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a reactjs app. I am trying to list users from the data of an ajax response. Below is the code.

```
const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }
    axios.get('users', config).then((res) => {
      if (res.status == 200 && res.data.msg == "success") {
        setUsers(res.data.users)
      }
      else {
        history.push("/");
      }

      feather.replace()
    });

  });
```

And I am using the code below to list the users in a table.

```
function getRows(users) {
    return users.map(user  => {
      const { u_id, username } = user;
      return (
        <tr key={u_id} id={u_id}>
          <td>{u_id}</td>
          <td>{username}</td>
          <td class="delete">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-feather="edit"></span></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={(e) => deleteUser(e, u_id)}><span data-feather="trash"></span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    });
  }
```

Now the problem is that it is generating an endless loop of requests to fetch the users. I think it is because each time the state changes react is calling the `useEffect` hook. How to fix this.

Comment: use blank array at end of `useeffect` so it will look like `},[] )`

Comment: @CodeBug       Cool!. worked!

Comment: @Akhilesh you must use an empty array as a second argument to stop the triggering effect on component update.

Here is a useful article on useEffect and data fetching  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: useEffect without dependency = run effect on every render. 
useEffect with empty `[]` dependency = run effect only once. 
useEffect with dependency `[some_state]` = run effect on every `some_state` change.

Comment: will add an answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 useEffect(() => {
const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
}
axios.get('users', config).then((res) => {
  if (res.status == 200 && res.data.msg == "success") {
    setUsers(res.data.users)
  }
  else {
    history.push("/");
  }

  feather.replace()
  });
}, []);
```

note here I passed the empty `array[]` as the second argument for useEffect,

**Reason of empty array at useEffect**

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on the mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to be re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

read more about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add an empty array as `useEffect` dependency, so it only run once:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
  };
  axios.get("users", config).then((res) => {
    if (res.status == 200 && res.data.msg == "success") {
      setUsers(res.data.users);
    } else {
      history.push("/");
    }

    feather.replace();
  });
}, []);  //<-- Add empty dependency here
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook basically accepts two arguments, the first one being the callback, and the second one is an array of dependencies (optional). The purpose of the second argument (array of dependencies) is to trigger the callback function, whenever any value in the dependencies array change. So, if you don't use the dependencies array in your `useEffect` hook, the callback function is executed every time the component is rendered, i.e, whenever the state variables are mutated.

## So what's causing the loop?

```
const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }
    axios.get('users', config).then((res) => {
      if (res.status == 200 && res.data.msg == "success") {
        setUsers(res.data.users) //Updating state causes the component to re-render
      }
      else {
        history.push("/");
      }

      feather.replace()
    });

  });
```

Looking at your code, we can observe that you are using two hooks ( `useState` and `useEffect`) , so when the promise is resolved, you are updating your `users` state with the latest fetched information. So far, so good. When a state is updated, we know that the component is re-rendered (that's the basic principle on how React works). So updating the `users` state causes the component function to re-render, which would again invoke `useEffect` which would again update `users` state, and so forth.

### Workaround

To avoid this loop, we'd want to execute **useEffect**  only once, and not every time the component is rendered. This could be accomplished by passing an empty array as the second argument (Which basically tells React to run `useEffect` only when the component is rendered for the first time).

```
const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }
    axios.get('users', config).then((res) => {
      if (res.status == 200 && res.data.msg == "success") {
        setUsers(res.data.users) //Updating state causes the component to re-render
      }
      else {
        history.push("/");
      }

      feather.replace()
    });

  },[]); //Empty array as the second argument
```

This is similar to `componentDidMount` when working with class-based components.
Further, you could also add variables to the array that would cause the `useEffect` to be invoked only when the variables in the array are mutated.

Answer (score 0):

Add **dependency array** to you're *useEffect* hook , this will solve you're problem

this will act like component did mount

```
useEffect(()=> {
 /// you're code    
} , [])
```

but the one that you  used  acts like  component did  update  and  causes problem  because  you need  to execute the code only  when  component mounted